# Is a combined PHP/Java architecture possible

Tags: java, php, compatibility

Our current system is based on a Spring/Hibernate/Java/MySQL stack. We have a relationship with a company for which we will end up doing a portion of the IT work. They are currently building a system using an outside vendor which is based on PHP/MySQL. I would like to make an argument that they should reconsider and switch to a Java-centric platform.  My main argument is that we can utilize our current (Java-based) skillset for system maintenance and enhancements, instead of having a system which requires knowledge of both PHP and Java. However, they have asked if there is any *technical* reason why this couldn't happen.

It would be great if I could bring some technical arguments to table which show the two platforms are incompatible. However, I've googled the differences, and as far as I can tell, there wouldn't be any particular technical issues. For example, we could use web services for the systems to communicate.

So, the question is,  is there anything one could say about PHP which makes it either incompatible with or just not as "good" as Java?  E.g security, scalability and other enterprise considerations? I  know it's a vague question, but it would be very helpful to get some input.

Comment: I'd argue that a technical limitation would be the lack of knowledge of PHP required to successfully and securely integrate/maintain these two platforms...outside of that, I'm not sure of any overbearing limitations.

Comment: Q: Is a combined PHP/Java architecture possible?  A: That depends on how strictly you define "combine".  But the short answer is "Yeah, sure!".  *Especially* if "web services" is an option.  the whole *point* of web services is to integrate disparate, heterogeneous systems.  Integrating PHP and Java via a web service is definitely an option for you.  IMHO...

Comment: Your question is too localized. I can honor your motivation, but I'm not your consultant.

Comment: There are no security or scalability issues with PHP, no. In terms of integration, you may find the [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) useful.

Comment: There's also Quercus and Project Zero, two implementations of PHP *in* the JVM for easier interfacing.